# Can I call a function in a switch statement in php?

Tags: php

Is it not possible to call a function in a switch statement?  I am getting undefined function notice when I try to do the below.

```
class MyClass {
    function myfunction($var)
    {
        unset($var);
    }


    function checkValue($val)
    {
        switch ($val) {
            case 'hello':
                myfunction($val);
                break;
            case 'goodbye':
                echo "i equals 1";
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it may be because I am in an object, so it has to be $this->myfunction()

Comment: This is perfectly legal. But has `myfunction()` actually been defined? I mean, has it been included properly from another file?

Comment: Yes, there you go. You must use `$this->myfunction()`  It is not obvious from the code posted that this is in a class definition (except for a closing `}`

Comment: I've added in an example class name, as per your comment @Nicola. My advice to improve this code would be to switch indentation to tabs, rather than spaces - it makes it easier to line everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your assumption that you needed:

```
$this->myfunction($val); //Calls the instance method myFunction
```

Comment: did you copy paste that? This should work so I gues you have a typo, I´d test your sample but my dev server is down :/

Comment: I've used this in multiple projects. `$this->function_name();` does work. I didn't pass a variable to the function when I was writing out the answer so I guess I should have put `$this->myfunction($val);` when answering. My apologies.